# Mexc. Future API. Verify failed

Tags: c#, cryptography, dotnet-httpclient, signature

I want to place order in crypto exchange Mexc, but when sending a private request, I get this error:

> "Signature verification error".

I follow the documentation and the rules for forming the request and calculating the signature.

Below is the full code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string key = "";
string secretKey = "";

// parameters of request
string parameter = "leverage=3&openType=1&price=24500&side=1&symbol=BTC_USDT&type=1&vol=0.001";

// current time (Unix)
long time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

// concatenate params 
string param = key + time + parameter;

// calc signature
using var encryptor = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
var resultBytes = encryptor.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param));

var signature = string.Empty;
foreach (var t in resultBytes)
    signature += t.ToString("X2");

signature = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(signature);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://contract.mexc.com/api/v1/private/order/submit?{parameter}");

request.Content = new StringContent("application/json", Encoding.UTF8);

// add headers
request.Headers.Add("ApiKey", key);
request.Headers.Add("Request-Time", time.ToString());
request.Headers.Add("Signature", signature);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// {\"success\":false,\"code\":602,\"message\":\"Signature verification failed!\"}
Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
```

Link from the documentation for calculating the signature
https://mxcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/contract_v1_en/#authentication-method

Link from the documentation to the method for sending the order
https://mxcdevelop.github.io/apidocs/contract_v1_en/#order-under-maintenance

Please, help to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of StackOverflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the **Edit** option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AztecCodes The name of this site is two words, "Stack Overflow": See [How is Stack Overflow (the site) spelled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321191/215552). If you're using a template, you may wish to amend that. Also, you can make the [Edit] word a link that will allow the user to bypass the link by typing `[edit]` (using whatever capitalization you want).

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I have been working on the same problem and have all the remaining steps for automation setup but need a solution to making the API accept order placements.